# Search Disappears from header when copy default.xml

Tags: magento2, layout, search

So I copied `public_html/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` to `public_html/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<themeName>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

I did not change the contents of default.xml

And yet the "default" search that lives in the header next to the logo disappears…

If I remove the `<container name="header-wrapper">` section from new default search will pop back in.

This doesn't make any sense, since `public_html/vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` targets `header-wrapper` for the `topSearch` block.

So duplicated default.xml into my theme from the module shouldn't cause search to spontaneously no longer render?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to duplicate that file at all, that is the base file.

The file you have in your theme will replace the file in the base theme, e.g
/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

If you need to make changes to the base file you do so by moving, removing or simply not displaying elements via commands in your theme layouts.

Comment: But my theme doesn't have a Parent set and thus doesn't use `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Comment: OK, but it replaces that file in terms of functionality.
Basically there is no need to replicate the contents of the file you copied, don't do that, you will cause duplication which may break things such as the search. What are you actually trying to change with your local layout file?

Comment: I'm not trying to change anything right now, more getting to grips with Magento 2 really, so I can get a theme up and going.

Comment: OK, so just don't worry about it. You should not be trying to duplicate that file, the content of that file is there to modify the base layout, not to replace it.